# Se puede redireccionar desde un CONDICIONAL SWITCH, de cada opción deseo redireccionar a rutas diferentes?

Tags: php, laravel, redirección, switch

Se puede redireccionar desde un CONDICIONAL SWITCH, de cada opción deseo redireccionar a rutas diferentes?

```
switch (boolean)
 case 1
    ruta1
    break
 case 2
    ruta2
    break
 case 3
    ruta3
    break
::::::
::::::
default
    :::
    break
endcase
```

Comment: claro si se puede sin problemas

Answer (score 0):

Claro que sí, dentro de cada switch podrías poner lo siguiente:

```
 ...
 case 1
    return redirect('admin/example');
    break
 ...
```

En [este ejemplo](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/create-redirect-method-with-switch-statement) puedes ver mejor como se redireccionan las rutas dentro de un switch. Saludos.